# Нужно подкорректировать срез массива в Питон

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

В задаче дан список чисел из `N` элементов, нужно упорядочить элементы, лежащие в промежутке между наименьшим и наибольшим числами.

Не могу подобрать нужные параметры "среза":

Мой код:

```
from random import randint
num = int(input('Введите количество элементов списка:'))
mylist = [randint(-50,50) for x in range(num)]
print(mylist)
print(sorted(mylist))
print(sorted(mylist[1:num-1]))
```

Comment: У вас параметры среза подобраны верно, проблема в том, что вы сначала удаляете первый и последний элемент (которые еще не сортированы), а уже потом сортируете

Comment: Нет, неверно. При сортировке я ставлю в начало списка минимальный элемент, а в конец-максимальный. Их мне и нужно удалить.

Comment: вы не сортируете список, вы вызываете функцию sorted(mylist), которая не изменяет исходный список, она возвращает новый, а исходный ваш - остаётся прежним, и именно его вы сначала режете без сортировки, а уже потом сортируете

Comment: Павел, вы можете добавить решение? На слух несколько трудно ориентироваться)

Comment: могу, но не буду этого делать, это самые базовые основы, которые вы должны понять самостоятельно, без них вы не сможете дальше развиваться, направление я вам дал - дальше все зависит от вашего упорства. на этом сайте помогают решать задачи, но не решают их за вас.

Answer (score 0):

Суть в том, что вы не меняете исходного списка от слова совсем. Функция sorted() лишь берет ваш список и создает такой же, а только потом полученный список сортирует.

```
my_list = [2, 1, 4, 3]    
print(sorted(my_list)) # [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(my_list) # [2, 1, 4, 3]
```

Вы также нигде не сохраняете первый и последний элементы. Вы их просто отбрасываете. Вы можете сделать так:

```
first, *other, last = my_list
# print(first) -> 2
# print(last) -> 3
# print(other) -> [1, 4]
```

Тогда у Вас в переменные first и last сохранятся первый и последний элементы, а остальное отправится в other.
В принципе, это все, что вам нужно для этой задачи.